# Size Inspector Xcode 8.3.1 not showing several options

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8

I am following the iOS App Development guides from Apple to learn about Xcode and Swift. There's one assignment where I need to select something in the Size Inspector tab. However, the option isn't listed there. I've searched the web for solutions but I cannot find any proper solution.

Do you guys have any tips?

Here's a screenshot of the Xcode window:

[image: Screenshot of Xcode]

Link to the Apple Guide: [Apple iOS App Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/WorkWithViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH6-SW1) (Looking for the Intrinsic Size option to select 'Placeholder.')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add some constraints, then option will be available.
Intrisinc size is size of image view content, which is used in auto layout process, without constraints it does not make any sense to use it.

After You add constraint You should have something like this:
[image]

Comment: It was not his case I believe. He definitely added some constrains as the screenshot is showing.

Comment: Thanks. I added a constraint and this made the placeholder appear. I didn't add any constraints just yet because the Apple Guide didn't say so :P. Anyway, thanks a lot guys!

Comment: he didn't, if he did then constraints should be visible in size inspector, while there is no constraints there, I've added a screenshot to show

Comment: there is a lot of thinks that apple dev documentation doesn't say, I recommend to use other sources of information ;)

Comment: @RobertJuz What source do you recommend then?

Comment: any other, there is plenty of through internet :)
mostly own blogs, apple doc is very raw as You can see

Comment: Karen's answer [https://stackoverflow.com/a/43709262/666818] is the right answer. Stacking the image view in the stack group will definitely add placeholder and intrinsic size.

Answer (score 11):

I had this same problem. When you dragged the Image View thumbnail under the button, it was added below the Stack View in the View Controller Scene. You need to move it, so the Image View is within the Stack View section (not under it). Once it’s inside the Stack View, the full list of options will appear in the Size Inspector tab. [Click here to see the Image View placement inside Stack View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPD72.jpg)

Comment: This should be the valid answer because just adding constraints won't stick the image view right below the button as it should be. Thanks, Karen!

Comment: This is the correct Answer! By default when view is dragged and dropped, it is placed out of Stack view. @Karen nice catch!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem following "Start Developing iOS Apps (Swift)" Guide and I followed Karen's comment, it worked!

You have to drag the ImageView from Object Library to inside the frame of the stackView on the storyboard. The Intrinsic Size field will then show up on the Size Inspector window.

If you drag the ImageView to outside the frame of the stackView, this Intrinsic Size field won't show up.

Comment: Please don't add `thanks` as answers. They don't actually provide an answer to the question, and can be perceived as noise by its future visitors. Once you [earn](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/146472) enough [reputation](//stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will gain privileges to [upvote answers](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) you like. This way future visitors of the question will see a higher vote count on that answer, and the answerer will also be rewarded with reputation points. See [Why is voting important](//stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote).

Answer (score 1):

You have selected something (this is a `View` behind your `ImageView`) other than your `ImageView`. Try to select your `ImageView` from the document outline and your size inspector will show appropriate properties.[image: see this image]